# Pass formik validation errors to parent component

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I am creating a component that internally has other 2 components with Formik each one, I did it in that way because each internal component submits separately on blur.

What I want to do is, once Formik validates, the errors should be showed within the parent component.

This is a quick example of the structure:

```
<ParentComponent>
    <FirstInputField onChange={firstChangeHandler} />
    <Divider />
    <SecondInputField onChange={secondChangeHandler} />
    <ErrorMessages>I WANT ERRORS TO BE HERE</ErrorMessages>
</ParentComponent>
```

The first approach was to send an "onError(error)" to the child component and call it to update the state on the parent component with the errors but I am getting a warning.

*Cannot update a component (`parent`) while rendering a different component (`child`)*

So I'd like to see if there is another way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context Api to manage the error state would solve your issue.

Reference for similar implementation you can check this [post](https://realfiction.net/2019/03/11/use-reacts-context-to-display-an-error-message-somewhere-else).